# Class method pre-invocation hooking

Tags: php, class, oop

Is it possible in PHP 5.X to have a method in a class that is executed whenever a classes method is called, prior to the called function? I need this because i want to do some dynamic validation for the parameters used in the called function.

```
class MyClass {

    protected function preHook(){ echo "You are about to call a method."; }

    public function methodA() { echo "You called methodA."; }

}

$obj = new MyClass();
$obj->methodA(); 
// Output:  "You called methodA."
// Desired output: "You are about to call a method.You called methodA"
```

Also keep in mind the following:
The "methodA" needs to be public because reflection is used in the code in order to detect the method.

Comment: The simple answer is "No"; and while magic methods like __call could simulate this, you're excluding those by forcing methodA to be public

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned in comment this is impossible as __call magic method gets called only if method with given name is not defined:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php

However, maybe one of the following hackish solutions will solve your issue.

**SOLUTION 1**

will require changing all your methods names:

```
class MyClass {

    public function __call($name, $arguments){
        echo "You are about to call $name method.";
        return call_user_func_array(array($this, '_real_' . $name), $arguments);
    }

    private function _real_methodA() { echo "You called methodA."; }

}

$obj = new MyClass();
$obj->methodA();
```

**SOLUTION 2**

this will require a 'wrapper' classes:

```
class MyClass {

    public function methodA() { echo "You called methodA."; }

}

class MyClassWrapper {

    public function __construct(){
        $this->myClass = new MyClass();
    }

    public function __call($name, $arguments){
        echo "You are about to call $name method.";
        return call_user_func_array(array($this->myClass, $name), $arguments);
    }
}
$obj = new MyClassWrapper();
$obj->methodA();
```

**SOLUTION 3**

Third approach would be to apply decorator pattern and create one wrapper class.

```
class Decorator
{
    protected $_instance;
    public function __construct($instance)
    {
        $this->_instance = $instance;
    }
    public function __call($method, $args)
    {
        print 'do your stuff here';
        return call_user_func_array(array($this->_instance, $method), $args);
    }
}

$obj = new Decorator(new MyClass);
$obj->methodA();
```

**SOLUTION 4**

mix of solution 1 and use reflection and "runkit_method_rename" to rename all methods
http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-method-rename.php
runkit is experimental so this is rather hardcore.

```
class MyClass {

    public function __call($name, $arguments){
        echo "You are about to call $name method.";
        return call_user_func_array(array($this, '_real_' . $name), $arguments);
    }

    private function methodA() { echo "You called methodA."; }

}

$reflection = new ReflectionClass('MyClass');
$methods = $reflection->getMethods();
foreach ($methods as $method) {
    runkit_method_rename('MyClass', $method->name , '_real_' . $method->name);
}

$obj = new MyClass();
$obj->methodA();
```

Comment: Hello, 1st example will not work because through reflection "methodA" is not detected. 2nd case will not work either because the reflection instead of happening on MyClass, it will happed in MyClassWrapper (since this is the one instantiated) and still reflection will not find "methodA".
Anyway, i found a workaround and "hacked" the calling class to call first a predefined method before calling any method found through reflection.

Comment: please see documentation for __call magic method. whole point of it is it is getting called when no method is found. Second option will call methodA on MyClass instance instantiated in MyClassWrapper constructor. Anyhow those were just ideas...

Comment: This will lead to too much wrapper classes.

Comment: @AlexLinte you can use one Wrapper class as well. You can also use runkit to rename all methods. I have added two solutions to my answer.

Answer (score -1):

In the end i modified the dispatcher to call the prehook (using __call in order to keep it hidden from reflection but still be public) before the actual method is called.